# Send all the aggregations as text with Watcher (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm configuring right now Watcher to search in the access logs and see how many error is so far and send it to a slack account. 
Well, the problem that I have is because I can't know how many aggregations I will have when the query is done and in my configurations is something like "hardcoded" to send just like 5 at maximum , but if the result is grather than 5 not works.

I'm searching for 404 status code in the query and filter only for one server, then I just need send all bucket results as notification as:

Total: Total-number-of-its
Logs:
log1: number-of-results
log2: number-of-results
log3: number-of-results
log4: number-of-results
log5: number-of-results
log6: number-of-results

Here my configuration:

```
  "trigger" : {
    "schedule" : { "interval" : "1h" } 
  },
  "input" : {
    "search" : {
      "request": {
      "body": {
        "query": { 
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-1h",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
                }
              }, 
              {
                "match": {
                  "beat.hostname": "someserver"
                }
              }
            ], 
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "response": "404"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "host": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "beat.hostname",
              "size": 1
            }
          },
          "logs_list": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "source",
              "size": 10
            }
          }
        }
       }
      }
    }
  },
    "condition": {
    "compare" : { "ctx.payload.hits.total" : { "gt" : 0 }}
  },
  "actions" : {
    "notify-slack" : {
      "throttle_period" : "30m",
      "slack" : {
        "message" : {
          "from": "Watcher",
          "to" : [ "somechannel" ],
          "attachments" : [
          {
            "title" : "400 code status found",
            "text" : "Encountered: {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} in the last hour on {{ctx.payload.aggregations.host.buckets.0.key}} \n Files: \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.0.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.0.doc_count}} \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.1.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.1.doc_count}} \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.2.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.2.doc_count}} \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.3.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.3.doc_count}} \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.4.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.4.doc_count}} \n {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.5.key}}: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.logs_list.buckets.5.doc_count}}",
            "color" : "danger"
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't know how should I send the "text" in actions, any ideas how should I pass all buckets result? 
Thanks in advance, i'm using xpack, ELK and logstash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to loop over your aggregation in the action.  Try this:

```
{{#ctx.payload.aggregations.myAggName.buckets}}
    {{key}}: {{doc_count}}
{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.myAggName.buckets}}
```